# MySQL max varchar index length exceeds 3072 bytes. How is this possible?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm indexing a table on MySQL that has a description of varchar(3000). I get the typical error you'd expect to see here, as such: `ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.`.

This does not confuse as having read other posts (e.g. [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes-in-mysql-5-6)) the max length I can use is varchar(255) in MyISAM or 3072 bytes in InnoDB. What is confusing me is that for years I've been able to index much larger varchar columns (5000 upwards), but this ability has now ceased. The one change I've recently made, which has caused me a number of other problems (mostly now fixed), has been installing MySQL cluster. I'm not using this yet, but I guess the install screwed with the default MySQL installed.

If anyone has any idea how I'd been able to index such large columns before I'd be very interested to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

> Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage
>   engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 1000 bytes long
>   for MyISAM tables, and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables. The NDBCLUSTER
>   storage engine does not support prefixes (see Section 17.1.5.6,
>   “Unsupported or Missing Features in MySQL Cluster”).

You may have used a full text index in the past ?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post an image, but I still have varchar columns indexed that have a 3000 limit. This shouldn't be allowed right?

Comment: what does show indexes from `table` show - its likely only the first 767 are indexed

Comment: `Cardinality: 16949345; Sub_part:1000; Index_type:BTREE`. Guessing the sub_part is referring to 767? If this is the case, how do I return it to the system before where when I indexed columns that exceeded the limit (presumably such as this one), it automatically indexes the first 767?

Comment: `CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));`  the sub part is 1000 so i guess its a MyISAM table ?

Comment: Yes it's MyISAM. What does the bracketed 10 do? Cheers.

Comment: only index the left most x chars, in that case 10 (took from the docs) so you would do (1000) or (767)

Comment: Excellent, that will solve it for now. Still no idea why I was able to do it without that before. Would you know why?

Comment: Was it though some GUI tool ? MySQL as far as i know has never just "corrected" this. its always something which has had to been specified

Comment: Nope. Had always been through terminal. It worked fine in workbench too. I find it odd too, though I swear it's true! Was a really convenient feature of my machine!